# How to find what vim default key binds does?

Tags: vim, neovim

Apparently `<c-space>` doing something by default in vim but I can't figure out a way to check what it's doing.

```
:imap <c-space>
> No mapping found

:h <c-space>
> Sorry, no help for <c-space>
```

Comment: Consider using the [vi.se] Stack Exchange for questions on Vim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a little hard to give a fully generic answer here and sometimes your specific platform or terminal emulator might have an effect on how specific keys are seen by Vim.

One way to try to figure out which key code is seen by Vim is to go into Insert mode and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> followed by your specific key. (See [`:help i_CTRL-V`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-V), which will tell you Vim will insert the next symbol literally.)

In my case, typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> in Insert mode shows me `^@`, which symbolizes the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>@</kbd> sequence, which shows me that's how Vim is seeing this key sequence.

(I believe this is mostly universal, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> will always generate <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>@</kbd> everywhere, but as I mentioned there are platform differences, so I can't guarantee it works that way everywhere, but you should be able to use the same <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> trick to find out if it's the same or not in your case.)

Following that finding, you can then look at [`:help i_CTRL-@`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-%40) to see that the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>@</kbd> sequence (which should be equivalent to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>) will "insert previously inserted text and stop insert."

Comment: Also, Vim's built-in commands and userland mappings are handled by two separate mechanisms so `:map` or `:imap` can't be used to figure out what a given built-in command does anyway. For that, one needs to do what you suggested: `:help <cmd>`.